# Scala type-level identity function in a type parameter

Tags: scala, types

I can declare an abstract type such as

```
type A[B]
```

and in a subclass define that as

```
type A[B] = Option[B]
```

if I want A to be an Option. And if I want A to be B itself, I can do this:

```
type A[B] = B
```

Can I achieve the same thing with type parameters instead of type members?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try a higher-kinded parameter:

```
class Foo[A[_]] { ... }

type Id[A] = A

type Foo1 = Foo[Option]
type Foo2 = Foo[Id]
```

Comment: Or even, `type Foo2 = Foo[({type Id[a] = a})#Id})]`

Comment: @retronym - you're wearing mismatched braces! One opening and two to close can't be right...

Comment: Thanks guys, this what helpful!

Comment: This time, REPL Certified™! `scala> trait Foo2 extends Foo[({type X[a]=a})#X]`